# CasperJS: Open a new window

Tags: casperjs

Have a link on the page:

```html
<a id="quote" href="quote.html" target="_blank">Quote</a>
```

Click it in CasperJS, but I can't capture the page in new window.

```js
casper.start('http://domain.com');
casper.thenClick('#quote');
casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('file1.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 4):

see also the documentation in casperjs about:

```
casper.waitForPopup();
casper.withPopup();
```

the new window(when clicking on link with target="_blank" attribute) can be considered as Popup.

document at: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforpopup

Answer (score 1):

CasperJS doesn't work with new windows. You have to manually remove the "target=_blank" before cliking on the link :

```
this.evaluate(function () {
    [].forEach.call(__utils__.findAll('a'), function(link) {
        link.removeAttribute('target');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
casper.start('http://domain.com');
casper.thenClick('#quote');
casper.waitForResource('file1.png' , function() {
this.capture('file1.png');
});

casper.run();
```

You should try to wait for all the resources to be loaded, then proceed with other job. This will always work.